# How to install wxPython under an alternative python version?

Tags: 20.04, python, python3, pip, wxpython

I'm trying to run an application (PsychoPy) on my Ubuntu 20.04. Due to some technical problems, I needed to use a diffrent python installation than my default. So following [this guide](https://hackersandslackers.com/multiple-versions-python-ubuntu/), I've installed python 3.6 and it works. The problem emerged while I was trying to install wxPython with python 3.6. Following [another guide](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2020/03/15/step-by-step-wxpython-python-3-ubuntu-20-04-installation/) and the official wxPython website, I typed in the terminal what follows:

```
python3.6 -m pip install --user wxpython
```

It seemed to work as it started to build the wheel but it ended up with an error. The error message is long. The last thing in the build report is:

```
"/usr/local/bin/python3.6" /tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/bin/waf-2.0.19 --wx_config=/tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/build/wxbld/gtk3/wx-config --gtk3 --python="/usr/local/bin/python3.6" --out=build/waf/3.6/gtk3 configure build
  Setting top to                           : /tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c
  Setting out to                           : /tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/build/waf/3.6/gtk3
  Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc
  Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)        : /usr/bin/g++
  Checking for program 'python'            : /usr/local/bin/python3.6
  Checking for python version >= 2.7.0     : 3.6.11
  python-config                            : /usr/local/bin/python3.6m-config
  Asking python-config for pyext '--cflags --libs --ldflags' flags : yes
  Testing pyext configuration                                      : Could not build python extensions
  The configuration failed
  (complete log in /tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/build/waf/3.6/gtk3/config.log)
  Command '"/usr/local/bin/python3.6" /tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/bin/waf-2.0.19 --wx_config=/tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/build/wxbld/gtk3/wx-config --gtk3 --python="/usr/local/bin/python3.6" --out=build/waf/3.6/gtk3 configure build ' failed with exit code 1.
  Finished command: build_py (0.795s)
  Finished command: build (4m37.280s)
  Command '"/usr/local/bin/python3.6" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
  ----------------------------------------ESC[0m
ESC[31m  ERROR: Failed building wheel for wxpythonESC[0m
ESC[?25h  Running setup.py clean for wxpython
Failed to build wxpython
Installing collected packages: wxpython
    Running setup.py install for wxpython ... ESC[?25lerror
ESC[31m    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-gbhtkl1i/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/jakub/.local/include/python3.6m/wxpython
```

And the very last thing from the whole log:

```
Running command: build_py
    Checking for /tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/bin/waf-2.0.19...
    "/usr/local/bin/python3.6" /tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/bin/waf-2.0.19 --wx_config=/tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/build/wxbld/gtk3/wx-config --gtk3 --python="/usr/local/bin/python3.6" --out=build/waf/3.6/gtk3 configure build
    Setting top to                           : /tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c
    Setting out to                           : /tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/build/waf/3.6/gtk3
    Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc
    Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)        : /usr/bin/g++
    Checking for program 'python'            : /usr/local/bin/python3.6
    Checking for python version >= 2.7.0     : 3.6.11
    python-config                            : /usr/local/bin/python3.6m-config
    Asking python-config for pyext '--cflags --libs --ldflags' flags : yes
    Testing pyext configuration                                      : Could not build python extensions
    The configuration failed
    (complete log in /tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/build/waf/3.6/gtk3/config.log)
    Command '"/usr/local/bin/python3.6" /tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/bin/waf-2.0.19 --wx_config=/tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/build/wxbld/gtk3/wx-config --gtk3 --python="/usr/local/bin/python3.6" --out=build/waf/3.6/gtk3 configure build ' failed with exit code 1.
    Finished command: build_py (0.716s)
    Finished command: build (0m1.376s)
    Command '"/usr/local/bin/python3.6" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
    ----------------------------------------ESC[0m
ESC[31mERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9uhulhbe/wxpython_053e05edce4148ecbc0f1844ca0d9b3c/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-gbhtkl1i/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/jakub/.local/include/python3.6m/wxpython Check the logs for full command output.
```

What can I do to get wxPython installed under Python 3.6 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: There's about five solutions: https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1599647177-Problem-and-Solution-for-Installing-wxPython-on-Ubuntu-20-04

Comment: None of which answers my question

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to install `wxpython` on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
python3 -m pip install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-20.04 wxPython
```

Comment: Yes, I've done that. Now I want to install wxPython under my python 3.6, not the default 3.8.5. The command you've given but with „python3.6” instead of „python3” gives me the error messages embedded in the main post. So what do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try

```
conda install -c asmeurer pango
```